# Reverse Chunks of a String

Tags: python, string

Write a function named reverse_chunks that accepts a string s and integer k as parameters and returns a new string that reverses the relative order of every k characters of s. For example, the call of reverse_chunks("MehranSahami", 3) should view the string in groups of 3 characters at a time, reversing "Meh" into "he_m", and "ran" into "nar", and so on, returning a result of "he_mnarha_sima".

If the string's length is not an exact multiple of k, the last chunk of fewer-than-k characters at the end of the string should be left in its original order. For example, if the call is reverse_chunks("MartyStepp", 4), the first chunk "Mart" becomes "tra_m" and the second chunk "y_ste" becomes "et_sy". The last two characters, "pp", are fewer than 4, so they are left as-is. So the result returned should be "tra_met_sypp".

You may assume that the value passed for k will be a positive integer.

Constraints: You should not create any data structures such as arrays. But you may create as many strings as you like, and you may use as many simple variables (such as ints) as you like.

(https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/python/strings/reverse_chunks)

```
def reverse_chunks(s, k):
    result= ""
    last= -1
    for i in range (len(s), last, -1):
        if i < len(s):
            result+= s[i]
            last= int(i) + int(k)
    return result

test #1:reverse_chunks("MehranSahami", 3)
```

```
expected return:"heMnarhaSima"
your return:"imahaSnarheM"
result: fail
details: incorrect return value
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question here? Stating the problem and posting code doesn't tell us what you need. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in a one-liner:

```
def reverse_chunks(s, k):
    return ''.join(s[i:i+k][::-1] for i in range(0, len(s), k))

reverse_chunks("MehranSahami", 3)
# 'heMnarhaSima'
```

Now, here's what goes on in that one-liner:

- `range(0, len(s), k)` produces "every `k`th value, starting at `0` and stopping at the largest multiple of `k` less than `len(s)`. For `k = 3`, that means we get `i = 0, 3, 6, 9, ...`
- `s[i:i+k]` takes the substring from index `i` up until index `i+k` - so, the next `k` characters in the string. For example, if `i = 0` and `k = 3`, then `s[i:i+k]` returns `Meh`. If `i = 3`, then it would be `ran`, and so on.
- Applying `[::-1]` to an iterable, like the string we just produced, is one way to easily reverse it (it means "take a slice from beginning to end, with step length `-1`").

Finally, we use `''.join(...)` to stitch these disparate `k`-character segments back into a whole.

---

Getting the *last* segment, if it's shorter than `k`, to not be sorted is more difficult. However, you can do it in a conditional:

```
''.join(s[i:i+k][::-1] if i+k < len(s) else s[i:] for i in range(0, len(s), k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are looking for something like that ?

```
def reverse_chunks(s, k):

    L = [s[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(s), k)] # this returns ['Meh', 'ran', 'Sah', 'ami']

    result = ""

    for e in L:
        result += e[::-1] # [::-1] reverses any string

    return result

print (reverse_chunks("MehranSahami", 3)) # this returns "heMnarhaSima"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, out of which the one that stands out most is modifying *last* inside the loop, which has no effect.

Here's a variant that I believe that does what you want (and also meets the constraints (*reverse_chunks*, at least)).

Note that the code can be much shorter, but I got a feeling this is more like a learning exercise, so I tried to keep it simple (and readable).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def reverse_chunks(s, k):
    ret = ""
    chunks_count, last_chunk_len = divmod(len(s), k)
    for i in range(chunks_count):
        start_index = i * k
        chunk = s[start_index: start_index + k]
        # Although it seems that theproblem is poorly written, posting the code as well. If this is the case, simply remocve the following for loop and decomment the line below
        for ch in chunk[::-1]:
            if "A" <= ch <= "Z":
                ret += "_" + ch.lower()
            else:
                ret += ch
        # ret += chunk[::-1]
    if last_chunk_len:
        ret += s[-last_chunk_len:]
    return ret


def main():
    for word, k in [
                ("MehranSahami", 3),
                ("MartyStepp", 4)
            ]:
        print("'{:s}' reversed ({:d} char long chunks) is '{:s}'".format(word, k, reverse_chunks(word, k)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056411752]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> 'MehranSahami' reversed (3 char long chunks) is 'he_mnarha_sima'
> 'MartyStepp' reversed (4 char long chunks) is 'tra_met_sypp'
>
> Done.
> ```

**Note**:
 As I also specified in the code, there seems to be a *problem* with the problem's text, regarding uppercase letters and underscore. If this is the case, then the current results are not *OK*, and you should:

- Remove the code between the 2 commented lines (in *reverse_chunks*)
- Decomment the 2<sup>nd</sup> one